# What determines which questions are tweeted?

Tags: support, questions, moderators, twitter, robots

Some (all?) SE sites have a Twitter account.  A selection of questions are tweeted there. Here's an example:

[image]

What decides which questions are tweeted?

Is it automatic (done by a bot), or do mods do it manually?

Either way, what are the criteria?

- View count?
- Highly voted question or answer?
- Evaluation by mods?
- Unanswered/needs attention?
  -Other factors?

Are these criteria the same for all SE sites' Twitter, or does it differ?